# How to add location based app shortcut to lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, lockscreen

[image: Example]

After many Google searches I have not found a clear answer on how these work. Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I assume the poster means the icons in the bottom right and left corners, but please clarify poster, and also include the unclear answers you found, maybe they're correct and someone here will be able to clarify them.

Comment: If your app uses beacon or region monitoring in the background then your app icon will appear when you enter a monitored region. If not then it is based on Apple's analysis of which apps people use in that location. There is nothing you can do in the second case to get your app on the lock screen aside from having a popular app at that location.